# PIVOTAL GPDB- External table gphdfs protocol command ended with error. sh: java: command not found

Tags: java, hadoop, greenplum

We have small array of Greenplum database.

**When trying to read External table in it**. 
**Getting error**

```
proddb=# select count(*) from ext_table;
ERROR:  external table gphdfs protocol command ended with error. sh: java: command not found  (seg0 slice1 sdw:
40000 pid=8675)
DETAIL:  
Command: 'gphdfs://path/to/hdfs External table revenuereport_stg0, file gphdfs://Path/to/hdfs
```

**We tried :**

Checked Java env on greenplum master host.

Also checked , Setting up - the parameters for GPDB

[gpadmin@admin ~]$ gpconfig -c gp_hadoop_home -v "'/usr/lib/gphd'"
[gpadmin@admin ~]$ gpconfig -c gp_hadoop_target_version -v "'gphd-2.0'"

But it is failing with this error

```
[gpadmin@mdw ~]$ gpconfig -c gp_hadoop_home -v "'/usr/lib/gphd'"
20170123:02:02:04:017762 gpconfig:mdw:gpadmin-[ERROR]:-failed updating the postgresql.conf files on host: sdw
20170123:02:02:04:017762 gpconfig:mdw:gpadmin-[ERROR]:-failed updating the postgresql.conf files on host: mdw
20170123:02:02:09:017762 gpconfig:mdw:gpadmin-[ERROR]:-finished with errors
```

Therefore ,Test for HDFS Access from greenplum host is not working.

```
Checked if  HDFS is accessible from any of the segment servers

[gpadmin@sdw1 ~]$hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://hdm2:8020/
```

Any help on it would bemuch appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a path issue to me .Please set right JAVA_HOME in hadoop-env.sh file

Also ,Please have a look into the following articles for better understanding on configuring gphdfs with gpdb .

[https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/202635496-How-to-access-HDFS-data-via-GPDB-external-table-with-gphdfs-protocol](https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/221492507-One-time-HDFS-Protocol-Installation-for-GPHDFS-access-to-HDP-2-x-cluster)

https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/203083906-Understanding-GPHDFS-Configurations

https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/221492507-One-time-HDFS-Protocol-Installation-for-GPHDFS-access-to-HDP-2-x-cluster

Thanks 
Pratheesh Nair

Comment: After setting the Java_home .  Still  getting same Error.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk18
export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/apps/hadoop
export GP_JAVA_OPT='-Xmx1000m -XX:+DisplayVMOutputToStderr'
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export KRB5CCNAME=$GP_SEG_DATADIR/gpdb-gphdfs.krb5cc
JAVA=$JAVA_HOME/bin/java
```

java_home 和 hadoop_home 要给具体数值，置于最前面，写成从环境变量获取JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME，GP处理时获取会为空值。